# Getting Distances from Nearest Function

Tags: nearest, distance

I am fairly new to mathematica. I am trying to find a way to mock python's KDTree.query function in mathematica. Basically I have 9 vectors (each length two). I want to know the three closest vectors to each vector and their distances. When I run the following code, the d matrix give me the vector and the index of the three closest vectors. Is there away to also produce the distances associated with these vectors? (besides using the distance function on each pair of vectors after generating the d matrix)

Thanks!

```
m = RandomInteger[20, {9, 2}];
b = Range[9];
d = Nearest[m -> b, m, 4];
m // MatrixForm
d // MatrixForm

Output:

m = {{4, 12},
     {17, 13},
     {9, 13},
     {7, 17},
     {13, 3},
     {14, 6},
     {20, 17},
     {11, 20},
     {19, 5}}

d = {{1, 3, 4, 8},
     {2, 7, 6, 3},
     {3, 4, 1, 8},
     {4, 3, 8, 1},
     {5, 6, 9, 2},
     {6, 5, 9, 2},
     {7, 2, 8, 3},
     {8, 4, 3, 2},
     {9, 6, 5, 2}}
```

Comment: Have you seen [`EuclideanDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EuclideanDistance.html)?

Comment: In M11.1+ you can use `Nearest[m -> {"Index", "Distance"}, m, 4]`.